# Mapping with shapefiles in R

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf

I have a shapefile with tons of different polygons representing different bodies of water (lakes, rivers etc.)

I would like to create a map of certain polygons. All of the current examples I could find only show how to plot shapefiles with ONLY the polygons wanted in them. So I am not sure how to only plot the specific polygons.

Link to the shapefile: https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/esri::usa-detailed-water-bodies/explore?location=45.461044%2C-84.374110%2C10.71

I would like to plot OBJECTID295061, 295018, and 295017

Current code:

```
library(sf)
shp = st_read("USA_Detailed_Water_Bodies.shp")
ggplot(data = shp) + 
  geom_sf()+ 
  coord_sf()+
  theme_bw()
```

Current map:
[image]

Comment: You can subset the shapefile like a normal dataframe, e.g.
shp_subset <- shp[c(295061, 295018, 295017, ]
or you filter with dplyr or base r

Comment: `subset()` or `dplyr::filter()` will help, like: `shp = st_read("USA_Detailed_Water_Bodies.shp") |> subset(OBJECTID %in% c(295061, 295018, and 295017))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `OBJECTID` is a numeric column of your data:

```
library(sf)
shp = st_read("USA_Detailed_Water_Bodies.shp")
```

Then you can make an "area of interest" subset like this:

```
aoi = shp[shp$OBJECTID %in% c(295061, 295018, 295017),]
```

Then make your plot using `aoi`.

If the `OBJECTID` numbers are the same as the row numbers you can select by row:

```
aoi = shp[c(295061, 295018, 295017),]
```

but I'm not sure because no time for a 250Mb download right now but I think this is correct.

Spatial dataframes from `sf` behave mostly like regular data frames, with a few weird exceptions. But for selecting rows and columns its not very different.